# ds must be an imagedataset

Tags: matlab, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement CNN on my image dataset. My dataset contains 1100 entries against them a response variable. Each entry contains 81 images. Here this is how I implemented it:

```
clear all
close all
clc

cd('E:\Project\Selected81\')
tbl = {'E:\Project\Selected81\00edff4f51a893d80dae2d42a7f45ad1', 1;
       'E:\Project\Selected81\0a0c32c9e08cc2ea76a71649de56be6d', 1;  
       'E:\Project\Selected81\0de72529c30fe642bc60dcb75c87f6bd', 0;
       'E:\Project\Selected81\1acbe17dc8f9f59d2fd167b2aa6c650f', 1};
options = trainingOptions('sgdm','InitialLearnRate',0.001,'MaxEpochs',15);
trainedNet = trainNetwork(tbl,5,options)
```

where `1`, `1`, `0`, `1` are the labels respectively.

But it gives the following error:

> `ds` must  be an imagedataset`.

I don't understand it as the paths I'm giving are to the image dataset.

***Updated Code:***

```
myfolder = 'E:\Project\Selected81\00edff4f51a893d80dae2d42a7f45ad1'
myfolder1='E:\Project\Selected81\0a0c32c9e08cc2ea76a71649de56be6d'
myfolder2='E:\Project\Selected81\0de72529c30fe642bc60dcb75c87f6bd'
myfolder3='E:\Project\Selected81\1acbe17dc8f9f59d2fd167b2aa6c650f'
cd('E:\Project\Selected81\')
tbl = { datastore(myfolder, 'Type', 'image'), 1;
        datastore(myfolder1, 'Type', 'image'), 1;  
        datastore(myfolder2, 'Type', 'image'), 0;
        datastore(myfolder3, 'Type', 'image'), 1};

options = trainingOptions('sgdm','InitialLearnRate',0.001,'MaxEpochs',15);
trainedNet = trainNetwork(tbl,81,options)
```

I'm using MATLAB R2016b.

Comment: That should include image filename as well. See the [***doc***](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/trainnetwork.html)

Comment: @SardarUsama I cannot give each image path. I used `datastore` tho. Please have a look and let me know.

Comment: Have you read the documentation link I quoted in previous comment?

Comment: @SardarUsama yes, This is how I came up with the updated code

Comment: If you have read it then you should know that you *can* give the path of each image

Comment: Can u please point out the specific line you are talking about in the doc?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, *"ds must  be an imagedataset"*, what you have is the path to the image directory *without the names of the images*.

You need to use [**`datastore`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datastore.html) or [**`imageDatastore`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.datastore.imagedatastore.imagedatastore.html).

```
% Using myfolder, myfolder1, myfolder3 in one go since they have the same label
tbl = datastore({myfolder,myfolder1,myfolder3}, 'Type', 'image'); 
tbl2 = datastore(myfolder2, 'Type', 'image'); 
tbl.Files = {tbl.Files{:} tbl2.Files{:}}.';  %Combining the files
%                 Label is 1 ↓                   Label is 0 ↓    
Labels = categorical([repmat(1,1,length(tbl.Files)), repmat(0,1,length(tbl2.Files))]) ;
% Above line is for the general case. If you have 1 and 0 as labels, better use:
% [ones(1,length(tbl.Files))] and [zeros(1,length(tbl2.Files))]  respectively
tbl.Labels = Labels;   %Combining the labels
clear tbl2;            %Clearing tbl2 since it is not needed anymore
```